# Cannot get module.id with ES6 with SystemJS

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I cannot find the equivalent of Typescript `module.id` for JavaScript ES6  with SystemJS. Is that possible to use CommonJS `module`in ES6 ?
I tried to set `moduleIds: true` in babel options but it's not working and documentation says

> Not available for common modules